# Is the AccuWeather API free for commercial use?

Tags: weather, weather-api

I'd like to know if the AccuWeather API is free for commercial use.
If not, how I can use it for commercial purposes?

Is there a totally free weather API that I can use for my app?

Comment: You'll need to ask them, although I doubt it. From the API docs: "Contact sales@accuweather.com to receive an API key."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Weather APIs free for commercial use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363052/best-weather-apis-free-for-commercial-use)

Answer (score 17):

Accuweather data is not free. They will quote you for a custom service if you call their sales support. At one of my previous companies (circa 2007), we were able to get a contract with them for national hourly weather across their station network very cheap, but still not free.

If you are looking for free weather APIs, Please have a look at [weather underground](http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/).

Comment: I can confirm this: I just received a quote for their most basic service (current conditions only) for $650/month, 3 months paid in advance, one-year contract minumum. Definitely not a hobbyist or independent-developer-friendly API. You will find no Googlesque metered usage model here. No 1,000 free requests per month, no $10 per block of 10,000 requests per month. Needless to say, I am saddened.

Comment: Wow, that is about 10x what we paid 5 years ago. They probably realized pretty quickly that they weren't making any money with that pricing, especially when they were providing custom feeds to everybody...

Comment: The question mentioned in the answer is no longer available. I wonder why? Anyone have a summary around?

Comment: @zhilevan Yes, only 500 requests for each day.

Comment: As of the time of writing - 30th July 2018 - Weather Underground no longer provide free API's.

Answer (score 3):

I have looked in many weather data providers looking for free weather APIs and i found that Accuweather is not free, try [yr.no](http://yr.no) I use it in my website via PHP

Comment: where is the API of the website you've talked about (yr.no) ?

Comment: @ErikEdgren Are there any special terms in using their service? Do they cover the whole world? Do they cap the usage of their service in any way? Do you need to register?

Comment: @androiddeveloper You can read the terms here: http://om.yr.no/verdata/free-weather-data/. Yes. They cover the whole world. At least the temperature. Please read the terms. No. You don't need to register.